# where is perl eval "...propagated" documented

Tags: perl, exception, eval, die

In the following code, `eval` checks whether an expression is valid.
It captures an exception, and my code prints out the exception, without the code dying at that point. So far, so good.

But when a `die;` expression is subsequently encountered, the exception text is printed out **again**, without my asking for it, with the addition of a `...propagated` message, giving the line number of the `die;` command.
But at this point, the exception text is inappropriate and confusing.
It seems that perl holds onto the `eval` error message, or exception message, until we reach a `die;`.

Below the code posted below are two workarounds, either of which makes the behavior go away.

Where is this particular behavior documented? What's the thinking behind it?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
my $str=q/(d/;
my $rgx;
eval{$rgx=qr/$str/};
if(length $@)
{
   print join('', 'qr/', $str, '/ does not compile: ',"\n", $@, );
}
print "Got past eval. But next, at 'die;', it will print an error message that no longer pertains.\n";
die;
```

Workaround (1). Give `die;` a nonempty string:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
my $str=q/(d/;
my $rgx;
eval{$rgx=qr/$str/};
if(length $@)
{
   print join('', 'qr/', $str, '/ does not compile: ',"\n", $@, );
}
print "Got past eval. Next, the nonempty string in die ' '; flushes out the inappropriate exception message.\n";
die ' ';
```

Workaround (2). Execute another `eval` which does not find a syntax error:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
my $str=q/(d/;
my $rgx;
eval{$rgx=qr/$str/};
if(length $@)
{
    print join('', 'qr/', $str, '/ does not compile: ',"\n", $@, );
}
print "got past eval\n";
$str=0;
eval{$rgx=qr/$str/};
die;
```

Comment: Workaround #3: `undef $@` at the end of your `if` block.

This is documented in [perldoc -f die](https://perldoc.pl/functions/die).

Comment: @ Jim Davis the `undef $@` is very helpful. I do not see that workaround documented in the link you give, but still you solved my implicit problem. I wish this was an "answer" so I could up-vote it. @ zdim answered the explicit question.

Comment: Oops!  Sorry, my sentences weren't related to each other.  I meant that to answer the "where is this documented?" part of your question.

Comment: @JacobWegelin I also think that there's no reason really for workarounds; why wouldn't one supply a message to `die`? I always want a message there, no?  Well, unless I want to propagate the last previous one.  In some rare situation (which I can't readily imagine) that you want a bare `die` then yes, you'd have to explicitly reset it, to empty string or `undef`.  (I'm not criticizing the question btw -- on the contrary, it's a good one, well resaerched and detailed :)

Comment: [cont'd]   In the case that for some reason one really needs to issue an empty `die` I'd perhaps slightly prefer resetting `$@` with an empty string (as opposed to `undef`), since that's `eval` behavior -- "_If no error occurs, `eval` sets `$@` to the empty string_"  (says `perlvar` on `$@` variable).  But then that would imply that you'd have to always do that, presumably after an `eval`'s error message has been handled, for any possible following bare `die`.  That'd be an unpleasant prospect, which I'd say practically forbids (in a sense) an empty `die`, except for error propagation.

Comment: Don't print error messages to STDOUT! They should be printed to STDERR (e.g. using `warn ...` or `print STDERR ...`). But why not use `die("qr/$str/ does not compile: $@");`???

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish by `eval`ing regexes without your program dying? If you are trying to evaluate user inputs within an eval statement, that can be a severe security issue.

Comment: @zdim I routinely use `die;` when developing code, to remind me where to keep editing my code. Your comment is helpful to me because I have much to learn about perl coding in general.

Comment: @TLP thank you for this warning. I am the sole user of my code. I wrote, and continue to augment, a big HASH whose values are regexes. I don't always remember what's in the HASH. My utility function enables me to quickly search the HASH, both its keys and its values, from several points of view. I give it a string and if the string compiles as a regex, it uses the regex to search the keys. If the string doesn't compile, the function tells me so.  It also checks which, if any, of the regexes among the values matches the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's fairly logical behavior, I'd say, with `die` used without arguments.   What is it supposed to do?

Documented in [die](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die)

> If LIST was empty or made an empty string, and `$@` already contains an exception value (typically from a previous `eval`), then that value is reused after appending `"\t...propagated"`. This is useful for propagating exceptions:
>
> ```
> eval { ... };
> die unless $@ =~ /Expected exception/;
> ```
>
> [...]

So issuing an unrelated `die` without any arguments gets mixed up in this facility.

Comment: No need for workarounds. One always issues a `die` with arguments, unless a previous error is meant to be propagated when this behavior comes in handy.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide an error message to `die`. If you don't, this is one of the possible [documented](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die) outcomes.

> If LIST was empty or made an empty string, and `$@` already contains an exception value (typically from a previous `eval`), then that value is reused after appending `"\t...propagated"`. This is useful for propagating exceptions:
>
> ```perl
> eval { ... };
> die unless $@ =~ /Expected exception/;
> ```

If you want to exit without printing anything, you want [`exit`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exit).

```perl
exit( $! || ( $? >> 8 ) || 255 );   # The value that `die` uses.
```

However, the following is a better and far more idiomatic solution:

```perl
my $rgx = eval { qr/$str/ }
   or die("Can't compile qr/$str/: $@");
```